# Are Twitter threads ordered the same for everyone?

Tags: twitter

I've noticed that on some celebrity Twitter threads, the tone of the replies will vary from time to time - but it's quite common that the top replies will all have a similar theme.

My question is - does everybody see the same content for a given moment of time, or is the ordering tailored for each user?

Answer (score 1):

It is not same for the all the users. I exactly don't know what is the logic behind that but it keep varying from time to time.